# Chrome is not loading my localhost with a subdommian

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, localhost

When i hit my local host to open my local site it dont perform any action it is working fine for firefox.dont know the reason.It has app before address.

http://app.127.0.0.1:8000/login

Comment: it may be caching your page, does the link work in Chrome incognito?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: are you using xampp or wamp or lamp? which one are you using?

Comment: To clarify, your site should normally be `http://127.0.0.1:800/login` but chrome prepends  `app.` to it?

Comment: Yes it does....

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a domain by editing your host file. Let's say your domain name is myapp.local.
Edit your host file and add the line

```
127.0.0.1:8000 myapp.local
```

Then in your browser, you just have to open HTTP://myapp.local

So with this configuration, you can use Laravel you can use the subdomain routine like so

```
Route::domain('{app.myapp.local')->group(function () {
    // put your routes here
});
```

Please keep in mind that this is for your development environment. You'll need to have another configuration with the real domain name when you go live.

Comment: Hosts file has these already but issue is still there.
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 app.localhost
127.0.0.1 app.127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're either usng xampp or wamp to create your virtual hosts ( subdomain for localhost). I'm writing method for xampp as you've mentioned the hosts file and configuring virtual hosts.

**For xampp:**

Follow the steps below to create a virtual host:

1- Change to your XAMPP installation directory (typically, C:\xampp) and open the httpd-vhosts.conf file in the apache\conf\extra\ subdirectory using your favourite text editor.

2- Replace the contents of this file with the following directives:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
       ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "<path to your website folder>"
       ServerName apps.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

This contains two virtual host configuration blocks:

The first block is the default or fallback virtual host, which is used for all requests that are not matched by subsequent blocks.

The second block sets up a virtual host named apps.localhost. The DocumentRoot directive specifies the directory to be used when serving requests for this virtual host (in this case, the WordPress installation directory), while the ServerName directive specifies the custom domain name for the virtual host.

To add more virtual hosts, simply duplicate the second virtual host block and modify the port number, DocumentRoot and ServerName directives as per your requirements. For example, if you want to use SSL with your custom domain name, you can add a new virtual host block for port 443.

3- Restart Apache using the XAMPP control panel for your changes to take effect.

4- At this point, your virtual host is configured. However, if you try browsing to the apps.localhost domain, your browser will show a failure notice, since this domain does not exist in reality. To resolve this, it is necessary to map the custom domain to the local IP address. To do this, open the file C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and add the following line to it:

127.0.0.1           apps.localhost

This takes care of mapping the apps.localhost domain name to the local machine, which always has the IP address 127.0.0.1.

On some versions of Windows, you will not be able to edit the C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file without administrator privileges. You can edit the file by right-clicking the Notepad icon and selected the "Run as administrator" menu option, then entering administrator credentials (if required) and clicking "OK" or "Yes" to proceed.
At this point, you should be able to enter the URL http://apps.localhost in your browser’s address bar and see your WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using chrome Developer Tools. You can access them from the menu or pressing f12 in default configuration. Try checking the console tab to see if you receive an error not present in Firefox (Same as chrome). This can help you troubleshoot if your site is having trouble on the client side or server side.

You can also check this answer and try to set your address in your host file or web server config to ensure your web server is actually responding through the address you need.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178734/add-a-prefix-to-localhost

Answer (score 0):

@Hassaan is right and in addition to that if you want to add virtual hosts in wamp you can just click on Add virtual hosts in wamp options and fill out the form to add a new subdomain in your localhost.